# How to smoothly resize LibGdx window

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to change my game window size. My tactic is to resize height when width is changed preserving aspect ratio (and viceversa). But when calling setDisplayMode, window blinks and is an ugly effect. 
I'd like to access to lwjgl object to change the window properties (then I could change viewport settings accordingly in LibGdx). Does exists a way to change window size in LibGdx without setDisplayMode? Or at least, does exists a way to access LwjGL object inside the application?

Thanks

Comment: LWJGL is only desktop. You might do that with platform specific interfacing yourself maybe.

Comment: I think I don't understand you. I'm working in a desktop only project.

Comment: You mean you want it to continuously update the surface as the window is being resized? If you're OK with it just resizing after you release mouse button, all you need to do is update your camera in the `resize()` method--no need to fool with `setDisplayMode` or LWJGL object at all.

Comment: Not exactly. I want to resize the window height when window width is resized, in order to maintain the aspect ratio of the window. Camera is updated later, when window has been resized.